# How to insert sample XML code in Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, markdown, code-formatting, xml

I am trying to ask a question which contains sample XML code but I can't paste sample XML code in the question. How it can be done?

Answer (score 23):

Note that if your XML doesn't get recognized despite the code block, you can add

`<!-- language: lang-xml -->`

before the code block. This has been elaborated in [this page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) and further in [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface-options-for-specifying-language-prettify/81970#81970).

Feature was added in 2011 so I realize it was not available at the time the question and the other answers were placed.

Comment: In the interest of someone stumbling into this problem in the future, [here's an example how to use it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17788888/revisions) (revision 4).

Comment: It worked using a shorter version: `<!-- language: xml -->`.

Answer (score 6):

You need to paste your XML, and then highlight the lines in question, and press on the "code" button (`{ }` on the editor toolbar).

[image: The code button]

This will nicely format and syntax highlight your code and/or XML.

Comment: You can't even imagine but this doesn't work for my XML :)

Answer (score 3):

XML is still a language so use the regular code button (its the icon with binary on it) otherwise use http://pastebin.com to post the code and then past the link here.

Not that hard

Comment: Please post sample XML in the question; not on a separate site.