# Interface options for specifying language prettify

Tags: discussion, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

I'm the maintainer for [Google Code Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/).

Markup authors can specify the language for source code, but not markdown authors.
Are the SO admins interested in a way of doing this?

If so, might the following work

1. If the first line is "#!" followed by one or more word characters, then make the first line invisible (using CSS hidden:visible) and use those word characters as the file extension.
2. Otherwise, use the current scheme.

So

```
#!css
tag.class#id { color: red }
```

would be recognized as CSS.

In markdown, should any indicator of line numbers survive copy-paste in markdown?

Does any scheme like this need to do work to handle quoting of responses in markdown?  Is it common for inline responders to split code sections?

Do users also want to number lines ( http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html#linenums ), so that others can respond with reference to particular lines?

Comment: It's a pity that the shebang with an interpreter name isn't counted as a hint about the language. (An example -- a bash script that could be highlighted accordingly if the shebang line would be taken into account: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6748083/how-do-i-find-out-what-git-thinks-the-top-level-working-directory-is/6748191#6748191 .) I'm used to that Emacs does this...

Comment: @imz: yeah, given the way prettify is supposed to be able to guess languages in easy cases, you'd think that'd be an excellent cue for it...

Comment: @Mike, can you please point me to some documentation on how to contribute a new language to Prettify? 

I'm pascal fan and really would love to see the pascal syntax highlighted here and there. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 168, accepted):

## Syntax Highlighting with “Code Prettify”

This is now implemented. See [Stack Overflow’s help on Syntax Highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting).

### Specifying a language for syntax highlighting

Besides tag inferences (a recent change), you can *manually* specify a language as a hint to [Google Code Prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/).

Here’s how:

```
<!-- language: «lang-or-tag-here» -->

    «code goes here»

«more text»

<!-- language: «lang-or-tag-here» -->

    «code goes here»
```

You may use either a **tag** or a **prettify language code**.  Prettify language codes are guaranteed to work, regardless of what language the tag happens to be set to.

> **Available Language Hints Moved**
>
> Due to several lists of available hints existing throughout Meta, the entire list has been consolidated and moved to the following FAQ:
>
> [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: @kevin, as there are no tags for "none" and "default": are those still somehow supported? (I also copied your edit to one of Jeff's [other posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78363/manually-specify-language-for-syntax-highlighting/81971#81971).)

Comment: What is the recommended language tag for 'make' or 'makefile'?  I guess 'lang-sh' is a reasonable approximation.

Comment: @Jeff, I guess my question is, do I need to bother on my vba questions using the prettify language code `lang-vb`, or should I just let my `vba` tag take care of it.  And then if the tag does take care of it, does it function better (or more smoother) if I use the prettify code?

Comment: @lance let the tags carry whenever possible, it's much simpler (and it fixes it for "everyone" when the tags "just work" as much as possible). Use Google Chrome inspector to view the CSS classes on the rendered `<pre>` to see what is actually finally happening in the post. That's what I do anyway.

Comment: I don't understand what's the difference between c and lang-c.

Comment: @User, `c` is a tag; `lang-c` is a Prettify language code. When a question is tagged `c`, any code in the question automatically gets highlighted with the `lang-c` language code because the tag is configured (somewhere) to be associated with that language code. The distinction is important for tags that don't have a specific language. For example, the `pascal` tag is configured with `lang-default`; there is no `lang-pas` language code. Manually marking code as `lang-pas` will leave it unhighlighted, but marking it `pascal` will invoke the default highlighting rules.

Comment: @RobKennedy: In Code-golf, nearly all questions are language agnostic. So there I mark my scala solutions `<-- language: lang-scala -->`. This shall always work, since there is a prettify tag for scala. Below the bullet list which ends in `lang-xml` there are more tags, `"bsh", "c", "cc", ...` - some of them are listed above, some are not. I still don't get the distinction.

Comment: That's right, @User. There are some Stack Overflow tags that don't have corresponding Prettify language codes. I mentioned Pascal. If I mark Pascal code with `lang-pas`, it won't get highlighted; Prettify doesn't currently support that language. If I mark it with `pascal`, it *will* get highlighted; Stack Overflow currently associates the `lang-default` code with that tag. It doesn't get highlighted *well*, but at least there's something. When Prettify eventually supports Pascal, the we'll re-associated that tag with `lang-pas`, and *all* existing Pascal code will get highlighted correctly.

Comment: From my experience the segment to be highlighted needs to be formatted as code or no highlighting will occur. If that's the case it should be stated here.

Comment: Latest release of prettify now looks for comments/processing-instructions of the form `<?prettify lang=...>` to better interoperate with translators that produce HTML like markdown.  (HTML5 specifies that `<?...?>` is equivalent to `<!--?...?-->`).

Comment: ok @MikeSamuel I will make sure the devs know! (I am no longer at Stack Exchange)

Comment: what about xpath?

Comment: Any chance of adding syntax highlighting for more languages, such as Windows command line for batch files or Windows PowerShell?

Comment: Why doesn't YAML have a tag? It's in Google Prettify...

Comment: The prettify language code for `c#` is `lang-csharp` but not `lang-cs`. Using `lang-cs` causes to turn on the default highlighting and doesn't highlight the `using` `namespace` and `virtual` keywords.

Comment: For an up-to-date list of supported languages, look at the [Google Code Prettify source](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsrc). Inside [`prettify.js`](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/browse/trunk/src/prettify.js) and all `lang-*` files, look at all `registerLangHandler` calls. The last argument of each call is an array of language codes. For instance, since `lang-vb.js` has `PR['registerLangHandler'](/*...*/, ['vb', 'vbs']);`, you can mark code with `<!-- language: lang-vbs -->`.

Comment: how to use more than one class without breaking the code block? in case of html, css and js all in one block?

Comment: I've created the tag [tag-syntax-association](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tag-syntax-association) for requesting association be made between tags and their corresponding language name (something only moderators can do)