# Syntax highlighting misinterprets shell code as C

Tags: support, stack-overflow, syntax-highlighting

For a post that is tagged with shell-script items ([bash](/questions/tagged/bash)) and not [c](/questions/tagged/c)/[c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)/[java](/questions/tagged/java), I was surprised when my answer to a question was shown mostly in grey (interpreted as a comment) when it hit the following in in my text: `for i in a/*; ...`

Please see
[Bash - Diff change header (name of files)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449411/bash-diff-change-header-name-of-files/5450415#5450415)

Comment: I don't think bash highlighting is supported, in which case it probably guessed it was C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Language inferencing is (mostly) based off of question tags.  In this case, that question has two language hints ([bash](/questions/tagged/bash) and [shell](/questions/tagged/shell)), so we fall back to guessing.

Clearly, [prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) is guessing incorrectly here.

There is a way to override this.  Just slap `<!-- language: bash -->` before the code block as [shown here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface-options-for-specifying-language-prettify/81970#81970).

Comment: it looks like 2 people already tried to edit my post to insert the language tag and it still looks as it it is handled as a "C" comment.

Comment: @nhed - the match is very exacting by design.  I've edited the post to conform to the spec.