# Markdown misinterpreting /* in code as comment

Tags: discussion, bug, markdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Syntax highlighting misinterprets shell code as C](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84917/syntax-highlighting-misinterprets-shell-code-as-c)

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586293/shell-script-to-append-text-to-each-file/5586445#5586445), everythng after the '/*' shows as a comment (but this isn't happening in the preview).  Is this a bug?  If not, how can I tell Markdown that this is part of the code?  I tried backticks instead of indenting, but then the indenting I had in the code was  stripped out.

Comment: make sure the question contains a **tag** that hints the code is shell code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have edited for you, like this

```
<!-- language: bash -->

    FILES=pathto/*
    for f in $FILES ; do
        echo "#extra text" >> $f
    done
```

Comment: @green in this case there were two strong "language" tags fighting which caused the syntax highlighting to revert to default. I removed the shell tag.