# Can we add how to disable syntax highlighting to the editing help (FAQ)?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting, editing-help

[*Syntax highlighting for code*](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) has a long section about syntax highlighting but it fails to mention how to disable it.

I guess one can use "lang-none" as a language code (it's listed in [Interface options for specifying language prettify](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface-options-for-specifying-language-prettify/81970#81970)):

```
<!-- language: lang-none -->
```

Is this correct?

I think it should be added to the FAQ. It's a special case, i.e. non-obvious.

Comment: If you use `<pre><code> ...<b>bold line</b> ... </code></pre>` instead of four-spaces in order to emphasise certain lines of code, then to disable highlighting, do: `<pre><code class="prettyprint lang-none"> ... </code></pre>`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That's a great idea; I've added it to the Markdown help page (will be visible after the next deploy).

Answer (score 6):

That's correct. It would be worth adding to the help page I think.

See also [Syntax highlighting language hints](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints/75019#75019) for the full list of highlighting options.

Answer (score 2):

I've found an alternative way to turn off syntax highlighting:

[image: just start a code block with ```none]

Comment: Which is already documented in the extensive FAQ on this subject: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work

Comment: I found this question through googling, plus this is less to read