# Why does syntax highlighting (sometimes) not work?

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

I.e. I just edited [Ninject Dynamically Loading a Repository from an Assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132751/ninject-dynamically-loading-a-repository-from-an-assembly) and noticed that there is no syntax highlighting/coloring.

**Update**: After adding the C# tag to the question, syntax highlighting now works.

Comment: Yet another good reason to add a language tag to questions...

Comment: @Cody Gray: not really, since the question is not about the C# language itself. It just happens that the OP used C# (but he could have used VB.NET and hit the exact same problem).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Code is highlighted depending on the [tags associated with it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting).

Since that question doesn't feature a specific "language" tag or one that allows the interpreted to guess the the fall back is unhighlighted code.

You could add a language specific tag to the question, or have a look at [Interface options for specifying language prettify](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface-options-for-specifying-language-prettify) for details on how to make specific code blocks be highlighted with a specific language colouring. The basic rule is:

```
<!-- language: (language identifier) -->

    code
```

Comment: Indeed, adding the C# tag solved it!

Comment: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting

Comment: Ah ha, that's a much better reference, thanks @Jeff. Favourited for future reference.

Comment: Why isn't the HTML comment working? It says it works even if there is no specific tag present, but it doesn't