# List of languages for syntax highlight

Tags: feature-request, support, markdown, syntax-highlighting, editing-help

When putting some code sections into SO questions, the system tries to detect the language and automagically colorizes the code but sometimes if the excerpt of code is small enough it cannot get the correct language, or renders no language at all (grey text).

By looking at some edits from experienced SO users I have found the `<!-- language: lang-xxx -->` trick to give the correct language to the rendering engine.

That [meta answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81971/173356) gives a list of supported languages but I have seen in SO some languages not listed here (like `lang-nsis`) and the [source of code-prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsrc) shows a list that is different of what is told here.

1. Is there an up-to-date list of supported languages for syntax highlighting in Meta?
2. Would it be possible to show it in the "markdown editing help" to keep it accessible easily?

Comment: You may want to read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101307/why-does-syntax-highlighting-sometimes-not-work. Syntax highlighting works based on the language tags in the question. The only cases I know where it *sometimes* isn't too accurate is when you mix multiple languages in posts (PHP/ SQL for example), also [CSS highlghting is disabled](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121816/whats-happening-to-syntax-highlighting-for-css-questions).

Comment: @Matt: Thanks, I have found also http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81970/173356 that gives a bigger list, but that makes several answers for the same question, with a different content. There should have at least one as a complete reference and to be maintained.

Comment: [This is probably what you're looking for. It's the source code files for Google Code Prettify - this dir shows a list of all the default code definitions.](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/tree/master/src) SO may be using extensions, but I've seen evidence of this and evidence to the contrary - so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81971) you found *is* up to date. We don't use all of the files in that [directory](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/tree/master/src), (which is why it contains languages you can't use here, like lang-wiki), and not all languages have their own files (because some are built into prettify core, like lang-sh).

There is no NSIS highlighting on Stack Overflow. If you found `<!-- language: lang-nsis -->` somewhere, that comment is futile. It will just use the default highlighter, which may look reasonable, thus giving the impression that lang-nsis is actually a supported plugin (has anyone actually ever created one?).

Comment: Why don't you use all (or more) of the files in that directory?  Is it purely a question of popularity?  If so, I think that you ought to look into adding [lang-vhdl](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/browse/trunk/src/lang-vhdl.js) to Electrical Engineering: [Support VHDL syntax highlighting](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/q/833) is our second-most upvoted feature request!