# Syntax highlighting for MySQL not working

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

See:

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7300401/revisions

It doesn't do highlighting when I specify `<!-- language: lang-mysql -->` (or if the question is tagged mysql), but it will work fine if I use `lang-sql` instead.

I guess it's just that mysql is not associated with any particular highlighting, but that's a little weird since it's one of the most popular tags out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three ways to achieve the appropriate syntax highlighting:

1. Use the default syntax highlighting for the language associated with the tag attached to the question.
   For example, supply no syntax highlighting hint when the question is tagged [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql)  which is associated with language "lang-sql"
2. Explicitly supply a syntax highlighting "lang" hint from the [supported language values](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface-options-for-specifying-language-prettify/81970#81970).
   For example, `<!-- language: lang-sql -->`
3. Explicitly supply a syntax highlighting "tag" hint that indirectly has a language associated with it.
   For example, `<!-- language: mysql -->`

For the answer you gave, any one of these three techniques would work but you mixed up the second and third techniques by combining the "lang-" prefix with the tag [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql), which works when tag and language names coincide, but not in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Read [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface-options-for-specifying-language-prettify/81970#81970).

It happens because

- **lang-mysql** is not supported
- **lang-sql** is supported