# Why doesn't SO syntax-highlight my PHP code?

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Syntax highlighting language hints](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints)
>   [Changes to syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting)

I just asked a question on SO [Facebook API scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355168/facebook-api-scope) and it's refusing to do a syntax highlight on my PHP code.

Is there anything extra required other than four spaces before each code line?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[As announced in 2010](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting) and specified on the [Markdown Help Page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting), you have to either to tag with `php` or use one of the [prettify language codes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface-options-for-specifying-language-prettify/81970#81970) (`<!-- language: lang-php -->`) before the code.

E.g.

```
<!-- language: php -->

    // This is some PHP
    phpinfo();
```

https://github.com/google/code-prettify

Comment: Adding `<?php` at the beginning break formatting.