# How do I get code to show up with color syntax highlighting?

Tags: support, code-formatting, syntax-highlighting

How do I get the following to show up (on stackoverflow) with color syntax highlighting?

class Foo
{
internal Foo()
{
for (int i = 0; i < 42; ++i);
}
}

Comment: Anyone editing that code block proper will nullify the question and its answers

Comment: For the list of all supported languages: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109

Answer (score 45, accepted):

See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help.

Basically, for code, indent four spaces -- you can do this by pasting code then highlighting and hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> or the <kbd>`{}`</kbd> button above the editing box.

As far as syntax highlighting, see [Changes to syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting) and [Interface options for specifying language prettify](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface-options-for-specifying-language-prettify/81970#81970).

The correct language will often be inferred by the tags on the question, but you can manually specify it with an HTML comment:

```
<!-- language: c# -->

    public static bool IsAwesome { get { return true; } }
```

or

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

    setTimeout(function () { alert("JavaScript"); }, 1000);
```

before the code block.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `language: lang-cs` per [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface-options-for-specifying-language-prettify/81970#81970)?

Comment: That is a quote straight out of the official editing help page. If it's wrong, that definitely needs to be corrected. There are four examples of syntax highlighting comments, and other three do use that format. I'll add the JS example.

Comment: @hammar: Both work; you can either use the prettify language code (`lang-cs`) or the tag (`c#`), because `lang-cs` is the default syntax highlighting language for the [tag:c#] tag.

Comment: The HTML language comment thing doesn't work. Not in this example, not in my posts.

Comment: @aalaap Did you do it exactly as shown in http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting ? Is the post on Stack Overflow or another site? They may not be exactly the same.

Comment: @agf It's right here on StackOverflow. I tried JS, C# and PHP, but all I can see is the <!-- language: xxx --> comment as a part of the grey, monospaced code block. That's what I see right up here in this answer too.

Comment: I have found that ```php also works.

Comment: @Neuron please don't make useless edits to an ancient post.

Comment: @Luuklag I don't think making a post more readable is useless. Also, what does editing have to do with the age of a post, if it is still very relevant for readers today?

Comment: @Neuron it's not relevant, as it was already closed as a duplicate 10 years ago.

Comment: @Luuklag It being a duplicate is not an argument as to weather it is relevant to some people. By that logic, we could delete duplicates instead of closing them. I got here by googeling `code highlight stackexchange`, and this is the first result.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert code inline like this `int i = 0;` use backticks: `` `int i = 0;` ``. If you want an entire block of code you can highlight it and then click the code button which looks like `{}`. You can also hit `Ctrl+K` while it's highlight, or just manually indent it all 4 spaces:

```
class Foo { internal Foo() { for (int i = 0; i < 42; ++i); } }
```

Comment: I don't see anything about syntax highlighting, which is what he asked about?

Comment: @agf That's because this is Meta not SO. Meta isn't for posting code, so it has no syntax highlighting. This exact post on SO will have syntax highlighting.