# There should an extra "code" type for error message

Tags: feature-request, comments, syntax-highlighting, error-message

When I write a question sometimes I would like to distinguish the error messages from code and also from my description of the problem.

Is there a way for text to appear in a box like code but to not be syntax highlighted?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This already exists.

You need to prepend error text with `>`.

> just like this

This is documented in the edit help under [`Simple blockquotes`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#simple-blockquotes).

Another option is to wrap the whole error in `<pre></pre>`.

```
Just 
Like
This
```

Comment: Indeed, this is actually used to Quote stuff (shortcut for `<blockquote>` tag wrapping ([example](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/118651/152859))) - as you quote error messages, it fits well. :)

Comment: but you have to put `>` per line. this isn't much of a problem though as error messages are usually one line.

Comment: @user152642 - If the lines follow one another, just doing this with the first would be enough (though you will lose formatting). Answer updated with another option.

Comment: This breaks as soon as the error message contains things that look like html tags/..., for example template arguments in C++.

Comment: @sth - True. For those instances, use the normal ` for escaping.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a code block and disable the syntax highlighting with a [syntax highlighting hint](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81970/160599).

```
<!-- language: lang-none -->

    error message indented four spaces
    ...
```

Unlike `<pre>`, this allows characters like `<`, `>` and `&` to be used without escaping.