# Why doesn't Stack Overflow highlight the "namespace" and "using" keywords?

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

In code blocks keywords "namespace" and "using" are not highlighted (e.g. for c# code).

`<!-- language: c# -->` does not help. c# tag neither.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Interface options for specifying language prettify](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface-options-for-specifying-language-prettify), [Syntax highlighting language hints](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/981)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I the correct method of specifying language highlighting is :

```
<!-- language: lang-c# -->
```

You were simply missing the `lang-` in the definition.

---

Check out the [formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) to learn all the methods/tricks with regard to formatting.

Hit edit on any post that catches your eye and see how they did it.

Comment: Gah, ninja'd due to lack of code.

Comment: @DanielFischer It's a mistake in [SO's Markdown help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting). That is why i've missed `lang-`

Answer (score 3):

Try it with `<!-- language: lang-c# -->`:

```c#
namespace name
{
    using foo
    {
        bar;
    }
}
```