# Markdown, how can I set the language highlighting display in Stack Overflow to ruby?

Tags: discussion, markdown, syntax-highlighting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Syntax highlighting language hints](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints)
>   [Interface options for specifying language prettify](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface-options-for-specifying-language-prettify)

How do I set the language being highlighted in Stack Overflow to be colored and formatted for ruby?

I've seen this somewhere but can't find it now.

Something like a one line option at the top of a file.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can't highlight a language with Markdown.  You need to outsource this to external libraries.  Such as.

1. [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/)
2. [Google Code Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/)
3. [Pygments](http://pygments.org/)

**EDIT:** The StackOverflow way of doing this is to have a comment at the top.  Like so.

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
```

Just replace `lang-js` with [one of the language codes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface-options-for-specifying-language-prettify/81970#81970) or a tag to set the language to the language associated with that tag.  For example.

```
<!-- language: c# -->
```

Highlighting for c# is associated with the c# tag.

(use lowercase letters, uppercase letters like `<!-- language: C# -->` does not work.)

Comment: Good point, my question was not clear so i added more detail.

Comment: +1 Yup, lang-rb for ruby worked for me (maybe I can do mutiple languages on one page even?)

Comment: I would assume so.