# Why can't I choose the programming language for Stack Overflow tag code?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, code-formatting

Why is it not possible to choose the programming language when I add some code in my question/answer? I think that it's a very important feature, since every programming language has it's own distinct formatting style, and it gets harder to read poorly formatted code.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The code highlighter takes a hint from the tagging of the question - so, if you tag a question with `C#`, it will attempt to use `C#` highlighting, if you tag it with `SQL`, it will try `SQL` highlighting.

You can also provide [language hints](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) in your post, using one of the [existing options](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface-options-for-specifying-language-prettify/81970#81970).