# Could you add syntax highlight of Cucumber scenarios?

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

Gherkin isn't in list of [supported prettify languages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface-options-for-specifying-language-prettify/81970#81970) and is highlighted incorrectly when using
`<!-- language: lang-default-->` (words that don't have special meaning in Gherkin are highlighted).

Recommendations on adding Gherkin highlight support are in section Tool Developers [here](https://github.com/cucumber/gherkin/wiki/tool-support).

Comment: You should ask [Google Code Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) to add the support for that language, as Stack Exchange just uses that to support syntax highlighting.