# Add Gherkin syntax highlighting (e.g. Cucumber, SpecFlow and similar implementations)?

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

Per the accepted answer to [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184108/972701), I am raising a new feature request here as this is supported by [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/static/demo/), but does not appear to work on Stack Exchange sites.

---

The [Gherkin language](https://cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/) is used to write automated tests using Behavior Driven Development. Cruising the bdd, gherkin, cucumber and specflow tags on Stack Overflow for example, you will see that questions frequently mix multiple programming languages. I haven't found a way to enable syntax highlighting for Gherkin yet. It tends to be highlighted using whichever rules exist for the main programming language tag on the question. This can look like a hot mess when applied to Gherkin:

[image: Screenshot of Gherkin highlighted using JavaScript syntax rules]

Example Stack Overflow question: [How I can pull data form cucumber table in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66899079/3092298)

It would be nice to add support for Gherkin syntax highlighting via:

````
```gherkin
@feature-request
@syntax-highlighting
Feature: Syntax highlighting for Gherkin questions on StackOverflow
    In order to prevent migraines
    As someone who answers questions about Gherkin
    I want proper syntax highlighting for Gherkin code blocks

Scenario: Asking for this feature on meta
    Given the user is logged in to StackOverflow
    When the user asks "Can we add support for Gherkin syntax highlighting?" on meta
    And while we're at it, I'd like a pony, too
    Then the question gets lots of up-votes
    And the feature request gets implemented
```
````

Here's a potential example of what I'd want this to look like:

[image: Tongue-in-cheek Gherkin example about posting on meta and getting this implemented.]

Note: I found [Could you add syntax highlight of Cucumber scenarios?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135237/972701), but it is almost 9 years old and was asked before highlight.js was used. I'm more than willing to roll this question into that one, but figured I would post a new question because it has been so long.

---

**Update 1**

I did a little more playing around, and tried:

````
```lang-gherkin
Feature: foo

Scenario: bar
    Given x
    When y
    Then z
```
````

And it was sort of highlighted:

[image: Screenshot of gherkin code block on this site]

A live example is below:

```gherkin
Feature: foo
    
Scenario: bar
    Given x
    When y
    Then z
```