# Edit adds HTML comment

Tags: discussion, edits

In this edit https://stackoverflow.com/posts/686163/revisions, the only difference I can see is

```
<!-- language: vb -->
```

Which adds 25 characters, if you include the addition of a new line. The edit is not visible, but does appear to offer a way around the minor edit rule. Is this valid?

Comment: That is not just a random HTML comment, that is a specific formatting hint.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, that is a perfectly valid edit as it suggests that the code block after it [will receive VB syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints).

There is nothing else in that particular question that suggests the highlighting needs to be applied. There are no relevant tags for example. This minor edit fixes that issue.

Comment: Sorry, just check again. It works. I know the feature, but the syntax deviates a bit from what I remember.

Comment: @nhahtdh: see [Interface options for specifying language prettify](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/81970#81970,) you can use either a SO tag, or a `lang-` prettifier language code.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: In the case above, it seems that a tag is used, which is why I was a bit confused. I only took note of the lang-* syntax.