# Parsing <pre> breaks with this content

Tags: bug

thanks everyone for the tips for the workaround, but what I am trying to do is report a bug with the parser.

if i try to put [this text](https://gist.github.com/6f807e50b6318377ab7c) inside `<pre>`, this happens:

Merge Left Join  (cost=14135.74..14138.08 rows=1000 width=16)
  Merge Cond: (generate_report.generate_report = (date_trunc('hour'::text, f.event_happened_at)))
  ->  Sort  (cost=12.97..13.47 rows=1000 width=8)
        Sort Key: generate_report.generate_report
        ->  Function Scan on generate_report  (cost=0.00..3.00 rows=1000 width=8)
  ->  Sort  (cost=14122.77..14122.81 rows=67 width=16)
        Sort Key: (date_trunc('hour'::text, f.event_happened_at))
        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=14121.93..14122.17 rows=67 width=8)
              ->  Hash Join  (cost=3237.14..14121.86 rows=67 width=8)
                    Hash Cond: (b.foo_id = f.id)
                    ->  Index Scan using index_bars_on_thing_type_and_thing_id_and_baz on bars b  (cost=0.00..10859.88 rows=10937 width=4)
                          Index Cond: (((thing_type)::text = 'Dog'::text) AND (thing_id = 26631))
                    ->  Hash  (cost=3131.42..3131.42 rows=30207 width=12)
                          ->  Seq Scan on foos f  (cost=0.00..3131.42 rows=30207 width=12)
                                Filter: (age((('now'::text)::date)::timestamp without time zone, event_happened_at)

Comment: Why don't you just use the standard formatting rule? Indent it with 4 spaces (or select the block and then press either the `{}` button in message editor toolbar or the `Ctrl+K` key)? This is clearly explained in the toolbar button tooltip and the code formatting help which is available behind the question mark on the right top of the message editor.

Comment: Because it is not source code. I don't want syntax highlighting (SO will guess wrongly about what language it is)

Comment: hey @Chichiray, why did you change my post so that my example of the parser breaking is no longer an example of the parser breaking?

Comment: and then changed it back i guess...

Comment: Sorry, this was an accident. I intented to edit my post, but your post was also in edit mode and I pressed the tab + enter key wrongly after making the edit in my post, causing your post to be submitted with the "fix" :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the `<pre>` manually instead of using Markdown formatting rules, you'd have to escape HTML special characters yourself. So e.g. the `<` has to become `&lt;` (which is also the root cause of your concrete problem; there's an `<=` in the last line which should be `&lt;=`).

Coming back to the reason why you intented to use the `<pre>`,

> *I don't want syntax highlighting (SO will guess wrongly about what language it is)*

just put `<!-- language: none -->` on top of the block to turn it off.

So, effectively, your post should look like this:

```
Blah lorem ipsum blah.

<!-- language: none -->

    Merge Left Join  (cost=14135.74..14138.08 rows=1000 width=16)
      Merge Cond: (generate_report.generate_report = (date_trunc('hour'::text, f.event_happened_at)))
      ->  Sort  (cost=12.97..13.47 rows=1000 width=8)
            Sort Key: generate_report.generate_report
            ->  Function Scan on generate_report  (cost=0.00..3.00 rows=1000 width=8)
      ->  Sort  (cost=14122.77..14122.81 rows=67 width=16)
            Sort Key: (date_trunc('hour'::text, f.event_happened_at))
            ->  HashAggregate  (cost=14121.93..14122.17 rows=67 width=8)
                  ->  Hash Join  (cost=3237.14..14121.86 rows=67 width=8)
                        Hash Cond: (b.foo_id = f.id)
                        ->  Index Scan using index_bars_on_thing_type_and_thing_id_and_baz on bars b  (cost=0.00..10859.88 rows=10937 width=4)
                              Index Cond: (((thing_type)::text = 'Dog'::text) AND (thing_id = 26631))
                        ->  Hash  (cost=3131.42..3131.42 rows=30207 width=12)
                              ->  Seq Scan on foos f  (cost=0.00..3131.42 rows=30207 width=12)
                                    Filter: (age((('now'::text)::date)::timestamp without time zone, event_happened_at) <= '24:00:00'::interval)

Blah dolor sit amet blah.
```

#### See also:

- [Syntax highlighting language hints](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints)

Comment: thanks, that's a good workaround. but the parser still has a bug AFAIK, and that's what i'm reporting.

Comment: See answer update then.

Comment: ::facepalm:: of course.

Comment: you may want to edit your answer so that the reason why my "bug" is not a bug is at the top, and the recommendation for a better solution is at the bottom.

Comment: Fair point. Edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `<pre>`; I don't even know why SO allows it. If it's a block quote, use `>`:

> Merge Left Join  (cost=14135.74..14138.08 rows=1000 width=16)
>     Merge Cond: (generate_report.generate_report = (date_trunc('hour'::text, f.event_happened_at)))
>     ->  Sort  (cost=12.97..13.47 rows=1000 width=8)
>           Sort Key: generate_report.generate_report
>           ->  Function Scan on generate_report  (cost=0.00..3.00 rows=1000 width=8)
>     ->  Sort  (cost=14122.77..14122.81 rows=67 width=16)
>           Sort Key: (date_trunc('hour'::text, f.event_happened_at))
>           ->  HashAggregate  (cost=14121.93..14122.17 rows=67 width=8)
>                 ->  Hash Join  (cost=3237.14..14121.86 rows=67 width=8)
>                       Hash Cond: (b.foo_id = f.id)
>                       ->  Index Scan using index_bars_on_thing_type_and_thing_id_and_baz on bars b  (cost=0.00..10859.88 rows=10937 width=4)
>                             Index Cond: (((thing_type)::text = 'Dog'::text) AND (thing_id = 26631))
>                       ->  Hash  (cost=3131.42..3131.42 rows=30207 width=12)
>                             ->  Seq Scan on foos f  (cost=0.00..3131.42 rows=30207 width=12)
>                                   Filter: (age((('now'::text)::date)::timestamp without time zone, event_happened_at) <= '24:00:00'::interval)

In this case, you probably want to make it a code snippet (indent each line by four spaces):

```
Merge Left Join  (cost=14135.74..14138.08 rows=1000 width=16)
  Merge Cond: (generate_report.generate_report = (date_trunc('hour'::text, f.event_happened_at)))
  ->  Sort  (cost=12.97..13.47 rows=1000 width=8)
        Sort Key: generate_report.generate_report
        ->  Function Scan on generate_report  (cost=0.00..3.00 rows=1000 width=8)
  ->  Sort  (cost=14122.77..14122.81 rows=67 width=16)
        Sort Key: (date_trunc('hour'::text, f.event_happened_at))
        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=14121.93..14122.17 rows=67 width=8)
              ->  Hash Join  (cost=3237.14..14121.86 rows=67 width=8)
                    Hash Cond: (b.foo_id = f.id)
                    ->  Index Scan using index_bars_on_thing_type_and_thing_id_and_baz on bars b  (cost=0.00..10859.88 rows=10937 width=4)
                          Index Cond: (((thing_type)::text = 'Dog'::text) AND (thing_id = 26631))
                    ->  Hash  (cost=3131.42..3131.42 rows=30207 width=12)
                          ->  Seq Scan on foos f  (cost=0.00..3131.42 rows=30207 width=12)
                                Filter: (age((('now'::text)::date)::timestamp without time zone, event_happened_at) <= '24:00:00'::interval)
```

Comment: Markdown allows by design a subset of HTML. It should have been a `<pre><code>`. But that's clumsy if you can just use Markdown formatting rules without throwing in some HTML yourself.

Comment: it's not source code. so if i use the 4-space indent, SO will incorrectly guess what language it is based on my tags, and give it meaningless colors

Comment: @John You can [tell it not to](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81970/145982); example [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/cb8ccad4-ded3-4b4f-a979-b53243ae7051/view-source)

Comment: thanks -- but i am trying to report a bug with the parser, i'm not looking for a workaround

Comment: @John What are you trying to use `pre` behavior for? Here on SE, monospaced text on an alternate background is used for code snippets. You can't insert marquee tags and expect them to work correctly, but that isn't a bug.

Comment: regardless of if my choice of pre is the best, AFAIK this is a bug with the parser. i thought that this was the appropriate venue for reporting bugs.