# Questions tagged with WiX should get XML code formatting

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow, syntax-highlighting

Currently if a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16549779/name-of-shortcut-created-by-wix-installer-to-support-latin-as-well-as-russian-ja) is tagged only with one of the [wix](/questions/tagged/wix)  tags, any code blocks in the question don't get syntax highlighting. Given that WiX is XML based, I think it would be helpful for the tag to trigger XML syntax highlighting.

Comment: As I am elbow deep in wix right now (and frequently trolling the answers in these tags), I've turned it on.  Also, ugh.

Answer (score 1):

You can [force a specific set of language highlighting manually](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) (doesn't go into the issue of WiX not being flagged as XML highlighting by default).

You should be able to [set in the block the XML language](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface-options-for-specifying-language-prettify/81970#81970) `<!-- language: lang-xml -->` to force the highlights.  If you look at your specific example, the first couple of lines of your post would be:

```xml
<Component Id='XYZAppShortcutFr' Guid='XXXXXX'>
<Condition>LANGUAGE="fr"</Condition>
<Shortcut Id='ShortcutFr' Name='Démarrer $(var.ShortcutName)' Target='[INSTALLDIR]$(var.TargetEXE)' WorkingDirectory='INSTALLDIR' >
```

Comment: [I started doing that](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/16567139/2) on some questions but then I realized that editing hundreds of questions didn't seem worth it if it can be done from the administrative side.