# Syntax highlighting a bit off?

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting

I had used this in a question:

```
cellNum = [VLOOKUP("string", '2012'!A:M, 13, FALSE)]
```

The light grey syntax color started at the single quote but then continued until the end of the line. Should it not have stopped at the next single quote?

[EDIT] No highlighting here? In that case, you can view it here: [Pass variables into VLOOKUP in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17729081/pass-variables-into-vlookup-in-vba)

Comment: probably using VB highlighting rules - ' starts a comment

Comment: According to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface-options-for-specifying-language-prettify VBA is not supported

Comment: @KateGreggory VBA != VB.NET and VB.NET _is_ supported through `lang-vb`.

Comment: @ColeJohnson I know VBA != VB.NET - the question title includes "VBA" so my guess is that is the formatting the OP wanted

Comment: @KateGregory ah. My mistake.