# Our syntax highlighting page should link to the syntax highlighting FAQ for prettify options

Tags: feature-request, help-center, syntax-highlighting

I'm referring to the [Syntax highlighting for code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) section in our editing help.

It includes this helpful line:

> You can use either [one of the supported prettify language codes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface-options-for-specifying-language-prettify/81970#81970), like `lang-cpp` or `lang-sql`, or you can specify a tag, and the syntax highlighting language associated with this tag will be used:

However, the link takes us to an answer on [Interface options for specifying language prettify](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface-options-for-specifying-language-prettify/81970#81970), which contains no list of prettify language codes. That answer in turn links to the FAQ question [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/152515), which *does* contain the list, and which the previous question is closed as a duplicate of.

There's no value now in linking to that intermediate page, so could the help article be updated to  directly link the FAQ question?