# Update help center on syntax highlighting to point to an actual list of options

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, help-center, syntax-highlighting

Reading the help center article on syntax highlighting, one of the paragraphs within it reads:

> You can use either [one of the supported prettify language codes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface-options-for-specifying-language-prettify/81970#81970), like `lang-cpp` or `lang-sql`, or you can specify a tag, and the syntax highlighting language associated with this tag will be used:

Note the link in there, which goes to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface-options-for-specifying-language-prettify/81970#81970).

Problem is, a long time ago we removed the list of options from several questions/answers across meta Stack Exchange because it was a pain trying to keep *all* of them updated. It makes a lot more sense to just have one list that we keep updated, and the most logical place for that list was in the [FAQ on syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109), which is where it now resides.

Can the link in the help center be updated to point directly to the list, rather than to a post that explains that the list has been moved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the sites that have overrides for the formatting article with syntax highlighting stuff mentioned have been updated to link directly to the relevant FAQ.

Comment: Hooray! Thank you! :)