# Supported languages on editing help doesn't actually link to supported languages

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting, editing-help

On [editing help page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help) <sup>(also seen on [StackOverflow's page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting))</sup>, the link about supported languages goes to [this page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface-options-for-specifying-language-prettify/81970#81970).  That page is a notification about the existence of syntax highlighting (though a [previous revision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/81970/1) does include the actual list).  The actual list was moved to [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work).

It would make sense to update the help center to link to that page.