# Update the syntax highlighting help with current meta links

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting, help

The [syntax highlighting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) links to [Changes to syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting), a locked thread focused on presenting a new feature and not of general interest today. It also links “one of the supported prettify language codes” to [Interface options for specifying language prettify](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface-options-for-specifying-language-prettify/81970#81970), but that post now only says “the prettify <s>princess</s> language list is now in [this other castle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109)”.

The second link should be updated to point to [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109). The first link doesn't really add anything to the text already present on the help page and could be dropped.