# Fix the link to Prettify language tags on the Markdown help page

Tags: bug, status-completed, editing-help

The [Markdown help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) page says:

> You can use either [one of the supported prettify language codes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface-options-for-specifying-language-prettify/81970#81970) ...

But the linked answer doesn't contain language tags - they have been moved [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/131247).

Can the [Markdown help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) page please be fixed to include the direct link to the language tags? The fewer clicks the better.

---

> [image: Our princess is in another castle]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build (build rev `2015.9.17.3693` on MSE/MSO, `2015.9.17.2825` on sites).